# Android app resume bug issue

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

This is not really a programming question but more of a debuging question.
I have an app that works fine, however, it is a bit unreliable when we try to resume the app.

What happens is, if we background/ minimize it, and than try to resume the app by clicking the app's icon.  It sometimes crashes and it sometimes doesn't.  It is unreliable that we can not trace what is the issue and why it occurs.

Any possible solution or places we can start tracing for the issue, please advise me :)

Cheers

Comment: Stacktrace or logcat, please.

Comment: What development environment are you using?

Comment: This is not really a programming question???

Answer (score 1):

Not a programming question but it is a development question.  It is extremely inconsistent didn't know how to even find the stack-trace

How I solved it was wrapped everything with a bunch of try catch and print the error stacktrace to the screen(or email the developer), finally found out the error was with one of the 3rd party LocationService library I was using.

Note: Location Service is not very reliable, please be caution in how you want to use that feature Android Devs!